# C# date time try parse not parse valid date time

Tags: c#

In C# when I pass a date examples like. mm/dd/yyyy...

It shows these results after parse

```
 // Example 1
 DateTime t = new DateTime();
 DateTime.TryParse("02/06/2013 00:00:00 PM", out t)

 // Example 2
 DateTime t = new DateTime();
 DateTime.TryParse("02/06/2013 00:00:10 PM", out t)

 // Example 3
 DateTime t = new DateTime();
 DateTime.TryParse("02/06/2013 00:10:10 PM", out t)
```

results are

```
2/6/2013 12:00:00 PM
2/6/2013 12:00:10 PM
2/6/2013 12:10:10 PM
```

Which shows incorrect dates while passing the date in sql server. How to resolve these type or issues. If these type of dates are invalid.

Comment: You're american aren't you?

Comment: Use sql-parameters! Don't convert it back to string and concatenate your sql-query.

Comment: what is invalid about them? there is no such time as `00:00:00` its `12:59:59` then `1:00:00`

Comment: Inputs are odd. 00:00:?? doesn't exist in 12 hour format! It should be 12:00:?? - however, it is being parsed correctly and output correctly as 12:00:??

Answer (score 2):

You'll have better results if you can format your dates in the form of `yyyy-MM-dd` - otherwise you can have locale related issues

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) to parse a specific format, regardless of culture. I believe you need dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss PM.

Answer (score 2):

Can use DateTime.ParseExact or DateTime.TryParseExact

For eg.

```
    string dateString = "Mon 16 Jun 8:30 AM 2008"; //Valid
    string format = "ddd dd MMM h:mm tt yyyy";
DateTime dateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime); // 6/16/2008 8:30:00 AM 
}
```

**Parse DateTime for UTC**

DateTime.ParseExact(inputDate, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.0000000Z", null).ToUniversalTime();

**Parse DateTime with Format M/d/yyyy**

DateTime.ParseExact(inputDate, "M/d/yyyy h:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Answer (score 0):

The parses you exhibit seem alright. They do depend heavily on the current culture of the current thread. Specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as format provider in the `TryParse` call if you don't like that.

Your question about a SQL server is unclear. What SQL software, and what locale settings does that server have? How do you communicate with it?

Once you have your `DateTime` value `t`, you can format it in many ways. For example you can use

```
t.ToString("O")
```

to get a "big-endian" string with full precision. See [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

PS! You don't have to assign `t` when you declare it (when it is going to be used for an `out` argument).